# Upload a file as part of logging in with ssh?

Tags: ssh

Here's question that some may find is pretty exotic (and it may well be impossible): is it possible in some way to upload a file at the same time as I log in? Something like:

```
$ ssh --some-option /file/to/be/uploaded user@server
```

Something like first using `scp` to upload the file, then logging in, but only giving the password once. The thing is, I always have to do this (don't ask, just don't...)

Alternatively, is there a way to sort of 'bundle' several of the ssh-family commands together, so you only need to give the password once (I know about using private/public keys - that's not what I want)?

***Edit 1***

Not quite a duplicate: It turns out to conflict with the following (which I have to use):

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If I use connection sharing, it seems to disable whatever ssh-agent does. Is there a way around that?

***Edit 2***

I made the following modifications:

```
$ cat .profile
...
function ssh
{
  h=$1
  /usr/bin/scp ~/mybashrc $h:.bashrc
  /usr/bin/scp ~/.vimrc $h:.vimrc
  /usr/bin/ssh $h
}

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
...
Host *
        ForwardAgent yes
        User myuser
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
        ControlMaster auto
        ControlPersist yes
```

Without the `Control*` options, I can log in to the bastion server, then on to other servers in that network, but when I add the options, I get the following:

```
$ ssh rgs-gameiom
mybashrc             100%  177    18.0KB/s   00:00
.vimrc               100%   59     3.5KB/s   00:00
Last login: Thu Oct  3 08:35:38 2019 from 80.229.227.116
$ ssh db3
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Search this site for `ControlPath` and connection sharing.

Comment: @grawity Just as I saved my edit :-) I'll try that, thx.

Comment: It works, but ... (see edit)

Comment: It feels like "connection sharing doesn't work with ssh-agent" (it does) ought to be a separate thread, but regardless, could you edit in a more complete demonstration of how you're doing it?

Comment: Edit added - should I create this as a new question now, do you think?

Comment: (1) Accepted answer indicates the problem is solved. Please do not put "solved" in title. (2) If you have your own solution, you should write your own answer. Questions should be questions, answers should be answers.

Comment: I put SOLVED in the title because I find it helpful when I search for answers on stackexchange. And I wrote up a summary, giving full credits to grawity, of the answer that I accepted, because I feel that seeing how I implemented his answer, would be helpful to others.

Comment: Still this is not how the site is supposed to work. [Write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) if you want to share your specific solution (You don't have to retype, your answer published as a part of the question is available in the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1488647/revisions).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSHv2 supports connection multiplexing – starting several command sessions over the same connection. Several existing threads on activating it:

- [Cache the password if SSH-keys are forbidden](https://superuser.com/questions/1362894/cache-the-password-if-ssh-keys-are-forbidden)
- [Can I start a new SSH terminal without re-authenticating?](https://superuser.com/questions/299871/can-i-start-a-new-ssh-terminal-without-re-authenticating)
- [ssh: leave channel open for fast copies](https://superuser.com/questions/186589/ssh-leave-channel-open-for-fast-copies)
- [How can I run `make` and retrieve the binary from a remote host without `ssh`ing twice?](https://superuser.com/questions/757948/how-can-i-run-make-and-retrieve-the-binary-from-a-remote-host-without-sshing)

---

> If I use connection sharing, it seems to disable whatever ssh-agent does. Is there a way around that?

No it doesn't disable anything.

However, with connection sharing active, *only the first invocation* – the one which actually connects to the server and prompts for credentials – will pay attention to your ssh-agent's $SSH_AUTH_SOCK.

This first connection will still use the agent to authenticate if needed, and it will set up agent forwarding if enabled.

But future "shared" sessions over the same connection are still piggybacking off **the original client process** (which remains running in background), which means they will continue using the *same* ssh-agent that the original connection used – they will not automatically migrate to a new agent socket.

So if you start the ssh-agent in such a way that it automatically exits after closing the terminal, this multiplexed connection will lose its "agent forwarding" after that happens.

To avoid this, either a) start ssh-agent in a more persistent way, and perhaps have it use a fixed socket location so that it'll be easier to restart at the exact same path,

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s -a ~/.ssh/agent-for-project-foo)
ssh-add
```

```
systemd-run --user --unit="ssh-agent" -- ssh-agent -D -a ~/.ssh/agent
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent
ssh-add
```

or b) avoid ControlPersist and manually start a "master" connection when needed:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add
ssh -fNM myserver                 # starts a background[-fN] master[-M] connection
scp somefile myserver:/tmp        # transfers a file without asking for auth
ssh myserver                      # opens a shell session without asking for auth
```

Comment: This has the look and feel of just what I want - I've accepted it; thanks a lot for helping!